# Assembly language programming declaration

Tags: assembly, masm

What do the following lines trying to say:

```
Hello:
     DB this
     DB 2
```

Please explain, I am confused.what should we say to "Hello". A label or anything else.
When will we use ":" and when will it not be needed.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but to answer part of it, based on my interpretation of [MASM documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/operators-reference?view=vs-2019#miscellaneous), `Hello` is a local label.

Answer (score 1):

In this code sample `Hello:` is a label that can be in a data segment or a code segment (or any other segment, for example, a stack segment - which would be unusual). It denotes the starting address of the following `DB` directives.

- `DB this` indicates a BYTE value of `this`, which may be a string equivalent(`TEXTEQU`), an equivalent(`EQU`) or even a BYTE sized address.
- `DB 2` just indicates an immediate BYTE value of `2`

So the value at the position `Hello` can be a 16-bit little endian value or an array of 8-bit values with the length of two, or a non-terminated string with the length of two.

Again, please realize that these codes can also occur in a code segment, where they would implement an instruction.

For example, if `this` is defined by `this EQU 0Fh` (and the second BYTE value is `02h`), the instruction at the label `Hello` is `0F 02 /r` = [LAR](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lar) with a register argument (`/r`).